# How to temporarily remove swift array members?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift2

I'm a bit new to Swift (so sorry if my question is a bit nooby) but...

So far my program takes strings in an array and displays them on the screen (Xcode)

I would like to implement a mechanism which makes it so that the user cannot get the same string twice in a row (when he/she presses the button).

My idea was to see if the random generated string is equal to the string already displayed on the label and (if thats true), delete the generated string from the array, run the function to display a random string from the array and then add that same string back after displaying a random fact.

Array of facts (in FactModel.swift):

```
struct FactModel {
var facts = [
    "Ants stretch when they wake up in the morning.",
    "Ostriches can run faster than horses.",
    "Olympic gold medals are actually made mostly of silver.",
    "etc..."
]
```

Function that gets returns a fact and the array index of that fact (In FactModel.swift):

```
func getRandomFact() -> (String,Int) {
let randomNumber = GKRandomSource.sharedRandom().nextIntWithUpperBound(facts.count)
let checkFact = facts[randomNumber]
return (checkFact,randomNumber)
}
```

My ViewController code so far:

```
    var mutableFactModel = FactModel()
    @IBOutlet weak var FunFactButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var FunFact: UILabel!

    @IBAction func ShowFunFact(sender: AnyObject) {
    let localRandomFact = mutableFactModel.getRandomFact().0
    if localRandomFact == FunFact.text {
        mutableFactModel.facts.removeAtIndex(mutableFactModel.getRandomFact().1)
        FunFact.text = mutableFactModel.getRandomFact().0
        mutableFactModel.facts.append(mutableFactModel.getRandomFact().0)
    } else {
        FunFact.text = mutableFactModel.getRandomFact().0
    }
}
```

It doesn't quite work the way I want it to, any ideas on making it work or a whole new way of going about it (not getting the same string twice in a row)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shuffle your `facts` array. Each time the user press the button, take the first element then remove it. Shuffling an array is akin to sort it in random order:

```
var facts = [
    "Ants stretch when they wake up in the morning.",
    "Ostriches can run faster than horses.",
    "Olympic gold medals are actually made mostly of silver.",
    "etc..."
    ].sort { f in arc4random_uniform(1000) % 2 == 0 }
```